# How to reassign the "Sign out" shortcut on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, script, autohotkey

I often find myself mistyping the "Sleep" shortcut as "Sign out". So I want to disable the shortcut for it, i.e. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>:

[image]

And reassign it to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>, how to achieve this using AutoHotkey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Log off button:**

Use Group Policy Editor (Admin Tools,  Start  and type Group Policy).

User Configuration, Admin Tools, Start Menu and then right side, remove log off from the Start Menu.

[image: Remove Log Off]

.

Then add your own keystroke keys to log off.

Here is a tutorial to help you.

[Remove Log Off](https://www.top-password.com/blog/remove-logoff-or-sign-out-option-from-start-menu-in-windows/)

> How can I remove “Sign out” from the Start Menu in Windows 10? Is
> there a way to prevent users from logging off a public computer? In
> this tutorial we’ll show you how to remove Logoff or Sign out option
> from the Start Menu in Windows 10 / 8 / 7.
>
> User Configuration, Admin Tools, Start Menu and then right side,
> remove log off from the Start Menu.

.

**Sleep Button:**  You can change what the Sleep button does in the Power Settings.  Start, Settings, System, Power and Sleep and set the Sleep button to "Do Nothing"